# How to monitor the destroy and instantiation of the GameObject in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to maintain a list of GameObjects in unity.

Using one of the `GameObject.Find` methods in every frame is expensive, so is there any method to monitor the destroy and instantiation of the `GameObject`s like a callback?

Answer (score 1):

> so is there any method to monitor the destroy and instantiation of the
>   GameObjects like callback?

No. There is no callback function for that.

One trick and the way I do this is to make a wrapper against the `Instantiate` and `Destroy` function then use those wrapper to create and destroy GameObjects. You can easily do stuff after the Object instantiated or destroyed.

Below is a simple wrapper that adds and removes GameObject from `List` when instantiated or destroyed respectively. You can even add an event and delegate to that if you want.

```
List<GameObject> objList = new List<GameObject>();

void instantiateObj(GameObject obj)
{
    GameObject newInstance = Instantiate(obj);

    //Add to list
    objList.Add(newInstance);
}

void destroyObj(GameObject obj)
{
    Destroy(obj);

    //Remove from list
    objList.Remove(obj);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> so is there any method to monitor the destroy and instantiation of the GameObjects like callback?

No, there isn't.

And even if there was, outside of garbage-collectors, tracking the instantiation and/or destruction (disposal) of every object is a bad idea anyway.

What you want is to manage only the objects that you need to manage, and in that case, a simple combination of `Factory` and `Disposable` patterns will do.

Look around the web for implementations of `Pool` patterns for Unity (or any other game engine, or even in general). They will provide nice examples of this.

---

Alternatively, as a simple implementation if decoupling is not an issue and you have specific `MonoBehaviour`s in mind, you can make the objects manage themselves, with a static `list` on the class, and making the objects self-add and self-remove on `OnEnable()`+`OnDisable()` or `Start()`+`OnDestroy()`:

```
public static List<GameObject> spawnedObjects = new List<GameObject>();

void Start()
{
    spawnedObjects.Add(gameObject);
}

void OnDestroy()
{
    spawnedObjects.Remove(gameObject);
}
```

Elsewhere, in a different class (or, most-likely, your GameManager):

```
foreach(var obj in YourClass.spawnedObjects){
    //Do something with every spawned object with a YourClass component here...
}
```